# Copy input into different cells with jQuery and data-class

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy, data-class

Multiple tables contain data in cells. If I change the data in a cell, they should also be changed in the same cell in other tables.

```
<table id="1"><tr><td data-class="row1_col1"><input...></td><td data-class="row1_col2"><input...></td>...<td data-class="rowx_coly"><input...></td></tr></table>
```

---

```
var dataClass   = $(this).data("class");
var dataChk     = this.checked;
$("[data-class]").each(function(){
    if( $(this).attr("data-class") == dataClass){
        do the magic:-)
    }   
});
```

But these solution is very slowly for big datas.

Is there a other way like:

```
$(this).data("class", dataClass ).each(function(){
    do the magic :-)
});
```

or a other solution?
Best thanks for helping

Comment: `$("[data-class='dataClass']").each(function(){ // Do magic! });` ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, it works fast and great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("[data-class='" + dataClass + "']").each(function(){ 
    // Do magic!
});
```

DataClass is a variable.
It works great also with big data sets.